# Inquiry about printing Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary called *top_words*.

I wanted to print its contents so I have written this code.

```
for word, count in top_words.items():

    print(word, count)
```

It displays something like this.

[image]

How can I remove the numbers before each rows?

The *top_words* dictionary is being generated by this function.

```
top_word_sequence = 0
top_word_dataset = {}

conn = sqlite3.connect('app.db')
selector = conn.cursor()

query = "SELECT word, count FROM top_words WHERE brand_id = ? ORDER BY count desc LIMIT 10"
selector.execute(query,(brand_id,))

top_words = selector.fetchall()

for single_word in top_words:

    top_word_sequence += 1

    word = single_word[0]
    count = single_word[1]

    top_word_dataset[top_word_sequence] = { 'word' : word, \
                                            'count' : count }

    return top_word_dataset
```

Comment: You have failed to show what `top_words` looks like, but I bet the key is the rank and the value is the data in a dictionary.

Comment: I mean, can't you figure it out from the printed output?

Comment: As Ignacio mentions, what does `top_words` look like ?

Comment: Hello, I have edited it, and added how *top_words* is being produced/structured.

Comment: just `print(count)` ?

Comment: I don't think it's a dictionary. If `top_words` contains the return value of the function (called there `top_word_dataset`), then it's an _array_ of dictionaries. You want something like `for dict in top_words: print(dict['word'], dict['count'])`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
for word, count in top_words.items():
    print(word, count)
```

Note: Using **print(word, count)** adds some other formatting to the output.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just want the values from the dictionary `top_words`.

```
for key, value in top_words.items():
    print(value)
```

Or, you can do it like this:

```
for value in top_words.values():
    print(value)
```